# Creating a shader why the compiled code in the editor show error identifier '_FillAmount'?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I checked so many time and the variable is declared but still it can't find it.

The Fillamount should set how much the circle will be filled for example value 0 the circle will be like ring and value 100 the circle will be fully filled.

Shader error in 'UnityLibrary/2D/Patterns/Circles': undeclared identifier '_FillAmount' at line 63 (on d3d11)

The error is on line 63:

```
// draws circle pattern
Shader "UnityLibrary/2D/Patterns/Circles"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _CircleSize("Size", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Circles("Amount", Range(1,64)) = 8
        _FillAmount("Fill", Range(1, 100)) = 3
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows vertex:vert
        #pragma target 3.0

        struct Input
        {
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float _Circles;
        float _CircleSize;

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;

        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        // https://thebookofshaders.com/09/
        float2 tile(float2 _st, float _zoom)
        {
            _st *= _zoom;
            return frac(_st);
        }

        // https://thebookofshaders.com/07/
        float Circle(float2 _st, float _radius)
        {
            float2 dist = _st - float2(0.5, 0.5);
            return 1. - smoothstep(_radius - (_radius * 0.01), _radius + (_radius * 0.01), dot(dist, dist) * 4.0);
        }

        void vert(inout appdata_full v, out Input o) 
        {
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);
            o.texcoord = v.texcoord;
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
{
    float2 st = IN.texcoord.xy;
    float radius = _CircleSize;

    // Calculate the threshold for filling based on _FillAmount
    float fillThreshold = radius * (_FillAmount / 100.0);

    // Calculate the circle value using the modified threshold
    float c = Circle(tile(st, round(_Circles)), radius);

    // Apply the fill threshold to control the filling
    if (c >= fillThreshold) {
        o.Albedo = _Color;
    } else {
        o.Albedo = float3(0, 0, 0); // Set the color to black for the unfilled part
    }

    o.Metallic = _Metallic;
    o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
    o.Alpha = 1.0; // Always fully opaque
}
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: you define a float for Circles and CircleSize but not for FillAmount... ? FillAmount is only mentioned in properties.

Comment: @BugFinder you right now the error fixed.  it's doing what I wanted but the error fixed. thanks.

Comment: yay i fixed a shader thing (I dont know squat about shaders but i can play spot the difference)

Answer (score 0):

you needed to add `float _FillAmount` to your `subshader`

```
// draws circle pattern
Shader "UnityLibrary/2D/Patterns/Circles"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _CircleSize("Size", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Circles("Amount", Range(1,64)) = 8
        _FillAmount("Fill", Range(1, 100)) = 3
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows vertex:vert
        #pragma target 3.0

        struct Input
        {
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float _Circles;
        float _CircleSize;
        float _FillAmount;  // Add this line to declare _FillAmount

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;

        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        // https://thebookofshaders.com/09/
        float2 tile(float2 _st, float _zoom)
        {
            _st *= _zoom;
            return frac(_st);
        }

        // https://thebookofshaders.com/07/
        float Circle(float2 _st, float _radius)
        {
            float2 dist = _st - float2(0.5, 0.5);
            return 1. - smoothstep(_radius - (_radius * 0.01), _radius + (_radius * 0.01), dot(dist, dist) * 4.0);
        }

        void vert(inout appdata_full v, out Input o) 
        {
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);
            o.texcoord = v.texcoord;
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
{
    float2 st = IN.texcoord.xy;
    float radius = _CircleSize;

    // Calculate the threshold for filling based on _FillAmount
    float fillThreshold = radius * (_FillAmount / 100.0);

    // Calculate the circle value using the modified threshold
    float c = Circle(tile(st, round(_Circles)), radius);

    // Apply the fill threshold to control the filling
    if (c >= fillThreshold) {
        o.Albedo = _Color;
    } else {
        o.Albedo = float3(0, 0, 0); // Set the color to black for the unfilled part
    }

    o.Metallic = _Metallic;
    o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
    o.Alpha = 1.0; // Always fully opaque
}
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```